# Can MeshLab managed the LAS data?

Tags: meshlab

Is it possible to open a las file format with MeshLab in order to do image processing? The las file has (x, y, z) georeferenced coordinates and the color (RGB).

Answer (score 1):

Meshlab can read ASCII text files containing points, or xyz files. You can convert las files to Text using [LAS tools](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/) and then import them. I believe you'll probably lose the color information.